# How to create properties for a Strategy Design Pattern in javascript?

Tags: javascript, design-patterns, google-chrome-extension, properties, strategy-pattern

https://gist.github.com/Integralist/5736427

this part of the code from the link above is giving me trouble. 
background: running in a chrome extension under "use strict" conditions

```
var Greeter = function(strategy) {
  this.strategy = strategy;  
};

// Greeter provides a greet function that is going to
// greet people using the Strategy passed to the constructor.
Greeter.prototype.greet = function() {
  return this.strategy();
};
```

I think i need to Create the property 'greet' but don't know how to.

I keep getting error saying "cannot set property 'greet' of undefined"

How can I create the property greet and get the code to work?

Thanks!

UPDATE this is how my code is in my extension

```
var MessageHandling = new function(strategy) {
    this.strategy = strategy;
};
MessageHandling.prototype.greet = function () {
    return this.strategy();
};
//Later
var openMessage = new MessageHandling(openMessageAnimationStrategy);
openMessage.greet();
```

Comment: If you don't use this extension, and try it in strict mode elsewhere, does it yield the same results? I'm unable to reproduce, but then again I'm not using whatever extension you're using.

Comment: Are you doing `var g = new Greeter(someStrategy);` and then `g.greet();`?  You will probably have to show us the code that uses the code in your question.

Comment: Yes I am using the var g = new Greeter(someStrategy); and then g.greet();

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is in the constructor definition `MessageHandling`. You need to remove the `new` keyword, because it doesn't make sense here.
Instead of  this code:

```
var MessageHandling = new function(strategy) {
    this.strategy = strategy;
};
```

use this:

```
var MessageHandling = function(strategy) {
    this.strategy = strategy;
};
```

The `new` [operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/new) is used to create object instances from a constructor function. You don't need to use it for constructor definition.